# Can't inject Cookie header when running Zap scan

Tags: zap

I previously asked for advice on how to inject a cookie (for authentication) when running a Zap scan. I was advised to use these env vars:

```
ZAP_AUTH_HEADER_VALUE - if this is defined then its value will be added as a header to all of the requests
ZAP_AUTH_HEADER - if this is defined then its value will be used as the header name - if it is not defined then the standard Authorization header will be used
ZAP_AUTH_HEADER_SITE - if this is defined then the header will only be included in sites whose name includes its value
```

So, I created these two:

```
ZAP_AUTH_HEADER_VALUE=Cookie
ZAP_AUTH_HEADER=jwt_token=<snip>
```

I assume it is not necessary to specify `ZAP_AUTH_HEADER_SITE`

But, when running a Zap spider scan, I can see that the the requests are not authenticated properly, and the requests are always redirected to the login page.

I made sure that I set these env vars before starting Zap.

Should this work? Does anyone have any advice on what can be going wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Handling authentication is hard, especially as so many apps work in so many different ways. We have pretty extensive docs here: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/authentication/